# spring social Facebook 2.0.2 cannot get email

Tags: java, spring, facebook, spring-social, email-address

I am using Spring social Facebook framework 2.0.2 and I am accessing an Facebook app version 2.5.

I, somehow, cannot grab the email address of the user that is authenticating via the fetchObject method.

```
@RequestMapping("/register/facebook")
public String registerFacebookUser(WebRequest request, Model model) {
    Connection<Facebook> connection = (Connection<Facebook>)providerSignInUtils.getConnectionFromSession(request);

    User profile = connection.getApi().fetchObject("me", User.class, "id", "first_name", "last_name", "link", "email");

    userConnectionRepository.createConnectionRepository(profile.getId()).addConnection(connection);

    return "register";
}
```

Id, first name and last name works perfectly but the email address seems to be null. I have registered an email address to Facebook, verified it correctly and is publicly available though.

My first guess is that the version used by Spring social Facebook is 2.3 when I look into the code. Do you think that might be that?

Comment: Did you ask the user for the appropriate permission?

Answer (score 1):

changes in facebook api might have caused this. Try the code below:

```
UserOperations userOperations = facebook.userOperations();
            String [] fields = { "id", "email",  "first_name", "last_name" };
            org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User profile = facebook.fetchObject
                    ("me", org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User.class, fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am replying to my question because I found what I was missing.

You actually need to give the permissions within the signin form in an hidden input. Pretty similar to the way you do it for the CSRF token.

```
        <form id="fbk_signin" action="<c:url value="/signin/facebook"/>" method="POST">                
            <button type="submit">
                SignIn with facebook
            </button>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                   value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="public_profile,email" />
        </form>
```

Permissions values can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5) on Facebook dev website.

Thanks to CBroe for his answer who made me look at this in the spring documentation. I wasn't aware of it.